# Flip Horizontal Animation using XML for ViewSwitcher

Tags: android

There are two views in ViewSwitcher. How to put flip-horizontal animation using xml? The current code does not produce desired effect.

```
<ViewSwitcher xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/view_switcher"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:inAnimation="@anim/flip_2"
    android:outAnimation="@anim/flip_1" >

    <include layout="@layout/no_appointment_card" />

    <include layout="@layout/appointment_card_profile" />

</ViewSwitcher>
```

**flip_2**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <scale
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="500"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:fromXScale="0.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" />

</set>
```

**flip_1**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <scale
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="500"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:toXScale="0.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" />

</set>
```

Here is one example to create horizontal-flip animation in Java.

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/JazzyViewPager/blob/master/lib/src/com/jfeinstein/jazzyviewpager/JazzyViewPager.java

How to create such horizontal-flip animation using XML?

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html

Look at this piece of animation from android

Comment: The minSdkVersion of cardflip example is 14. I want to run the horizontal-flip animation for Android API level 10 and later.